# Alter HTML Span With no ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, oracle-apex

I need to change the color of my pagination text so that it can clearly be seen against the background.

this is the span where the text is:

```
<span class="fielddata"> 
      1 - 50 of 3249 
</span>
```

I have tried:

```
$('.fielddata').css({"color": "white"});
$("div").children().css({"color": "white"});
```

I am not able to add an id to the span.

I am using oracle apex 4.2

Comment: Your first example, using the `class` will work fine (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/d39y5rvb/). Check the console for errors. Also note that you don't need JS for this; CSS is far better suited.

Comment: $('.fielddata').css({"color": "white"}); or $('span.fielddata').css({"color": "white"}); they all work ! May be something is being executed later and changing that CSS property. Or Like @RoryMcCrossan told you the Console would tell you which property is being ignored and may be there are other bugs preventing the script from working properly. Or  possible a cached js/css :) So you need to clear your browser data after updating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS, everything is specificity. Is the span element on it's own or is it wrapped inside a div? You can always increase specificity in order to increase the priority in CSS styles. For example, you can try:

```
$('span.fielddata').css({"color": "white"});
```

or, if it's inside a div:

```
$('div .fielddata').css({"color": "white"});
```

Comment: Note that specificity is completely irrelevant when using jQuey's `css()` method as it uses an inline style attribute

Comment: $('span.fielddata').css({"color": "white"}); did the trick, the second time I tried it, after clearing the cache. Thanks everyone!